# org.jxls,image can't display proper in each command

Tags: image, jxls

In org.jxls, the lastCell attribute of jx:image denote right-bottom,but not include.

When use image command in each, I will account a problem. I need a extra blank line to display image. Otherwise,I can't display it.

Best I could do:

[image]

Comment: for some reason createPicture(anchor, imageIdx) method in POI, used in jxls, fails to set the image properly if the anchor points to a single cell. It could be a POI bug or a feature. You probably should rise a bug in jxls issue tracker so that possibly some workaround for this behavior can be investigated and implemented

Comment: You are right.And I have solved this problem with Customer Command. I just added two line base ImageCommand,and solved this problem.